# Kubernetes - Does not accept updates in docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have changed one file in project and built docker image again. When I run it as a container, it works and I see the changed file in container.

However, when I restart kubernetes deployment using

`kubectl rollout restart deployment commands-depl`

deployment see unchanged file.

I also tried to delete deployment and create it again:

```
kubectl delete deployment commands-depl
kubectl apply -f commands-depl.yaml
```

Same result. :(

My K8s yaml is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: commands-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: commandsservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: commandsservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: commandsservice
          image: img-commandsservice:latest
```

Comment: did you update the image version in your k8s manifest?

Comment: You should include your deployment's yaml in the question.

Comment: I added my yaml into the description. The latest version of the image is selected

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes employ image caching mechanisms to improve performance. Check if your cluster is configured to use a cache, such as a container runtime cache like containerd or CRI-O. If so, the cache might be serving the old image instead of fetching the updated one. In such cases, you may need to clear or refresh the cache manually.

Check `/var/lib/containerd` or `/var/lib/docker` depending on which container runtime you are using.